# What does Fast and Slow Time Weighting signify for real-time audio signal processing?

Tags: matlab, audio, sound

I have a streaming audio signal that I am recording in real time. To make the explanation easy, say the signal that I receive is calibrated and has a sampling frequency, $F_s = 44100\textrm{ Hz}$.

I am then finding the Sound Pressure Level of this signal. For this purpose, I get a frame of audio data of t seconds.

Then, RMS Sound Pressure Level (dB) is given by:
$$
\rm Amplitude_{RMS} = \sqrt{mean\left(frame ^2\right)}
$$

This gives the instantaneous RMS of a $t$-second frame of audio. Then, to find a $\textrm{ dB}$ level, 
$$
L_p = 20\log_{10}\left(\rm Amplitude_{RMS}\right)
$$

Things get tricky here with the definitions of 'Fast' or 'Slow' sound pressure level. As [this](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/10544/exponential-average-with-time-constant-of-slow-fast-and-impulse) post points out, for time-weighted exponential average, I created a low-pass filter with a real pole at $1/\tau$ (where $\tau= 125\textrm{ ms}$ for 'fast' or $1\textrm{ s}$ for 'slow')

```
τ = 0.125; %fast
[b a] = bilinear(1, [1 1/τ], Fs);
frame_filtered = filter(b, a, frame.^2);
L_fast = 20*log10(sqrt(mean(frame_filtered)));
```

The IEC 61672 specifies the time weightings to be Fast and Slow for [determining the speed at which the instrument responds to changing noise levels](http://www.atp-instrumentation.co.uk/blog/time-weightings-fast-slow-impulse/).

- How does this work for digital audio?
- Does it mean that the analysis needs to be performed on a fixed frame of data?
- For this particular example, this frame would be $t\cdot F_s$ samples?

  ```
  Slow: 1*44100 = 441000 samples
  Fast: 0.125*44100 ~= 5513 samples
  ```
- If so, is it true that I would need to know in advance whether I need fast or slow levels?

Comment: this is about what we call "**meter ballistics**" and has existed long before digital audio.  the **frames** of data are not *fixed* in time, but are fixed relatively to the current sample, which i will call "$x[n]$".  this low-pass filtering of the RMS amplitude is really a **moving average** or a *weighted* moving average (with exponential weighting).  now, whether you need fast or slow really simply depends on how fast you need the virtual "needle" of your meter to move.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson Correct me if I am wrong, size of frame of data does not matter. As long as the τ of the Low Pass Filter is 0.125, based on definition, it will give me the fast level? The way currently I am implementing this is not a moving average. I am taking a frame of data, finding the RMS/fast/slow levels, and then moving onto next frame (not next sample) of data. So, for 10 seconds of audio, with a frame size of 1 second, I get 10 SPL output values - one for each frame. Similarly, for a frame size of 125 ms, I get 80 (=10/0.125) SPL output values

Comment: strictly speaking, for exponential weighting, the size of your data is from the present sample to forever ago.  if it were a sliding average instead (with equal weighting) the size of your data would define the meter ballistic speed.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson is the audio-expert here but afaics in this mode you are just computing the RMS of a **frame** (a block indeed) and converting that into dB SPL, then moving onto the next frame, where frame size depends on fast-slow response timing. But you have no **sliding window** here. What's your **purpose** of computing dB SPL? For a simulated analog Vu-meter, you should mimic the behaviour of sliding window to some extent; not necessaily one sample jump per computation but reasonably smooth jumps with **overlapping** frames (unless they are already short enough)

Comment: yeah, i wasn't paying attention until the OP pointed it out.

Comment: The reason I am implementing it this way is because [Python's Acoustic package](https://github.com/python-acoustics/python-acoustics) has implemented it in this way. Looking at the [fast_level code](https://github.com/python-acoustics/python-acoustics/blob/master/acoustics/standards/iec_61672_1_2013.py) {line 195}, this package gets the fast-SPL for a frame of data. I tried this code, for a 10 sec of audio, I get 10 slow-SPL output values - one for each frame of 1 second. Similarly, I get 80 (=10/0.125) fast-SPL output values since frame size now is 125 ms. This package claims to be IEC 61672.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson - So I've been reading about exponential weighting and as per [this post](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/10544/exponential-average-with-time-constant-of-slow-fast-and-impulse) I am able to use MATLAB's $dsp.IIRFilter$ with Numerator as (1-alpha) and Denominator as [1   -alpha] where $alpha = exp(-1/(44100*0.125))$ (sample rate = 44100 and time constant = 0.125). Based on your comment about weighted moving average, I am not sure if I can implement it usig [dsp.MovingRMS](https://www.mathworks.com/help/dsp/ref/dsp.movingrms-class.html#bu_1nj9-19_head)

Comment: i think that's a filter with $$ H(z) = \frac{1-\alpha}{1 \, - \, \alpha z^{-1}} $$ and that is indeed a one-pole filter where $\alpha$ is the pole value and the gain at DC is always $$H(e^{j\omega})\bigg|_{\omega=0}=1$$  that is an exponentially-weighted moving average filter.  the close $\alpha$ is to 1, the wider is the effective width your exponential window.  but theoretically it still extends back to $-\infty$ in any case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By "time weighting" in acoustics we are applying an RC (resistor–capacitor) circuit to a time signal.

See: [RC circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC_circuit) on Wikipedia

The time constant for FAST is 0,125 s and 1 s for SLOW.

You can also apply this digitally on your time signal by using my code below - it is basically a [exponential moving average filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average). I think you understand the steps by just looking at the comments in the code below.

> public class FilterTimeWeighting {
>
> ```
> private int nBands = 29; //number of bands
> private float initValue;
>
> FilterTimeWeighting() {
>     initValue=0;
> }
>
> /**
>  * Apply the LAmax RC-filter on the signal. Valid for fsamp=44100 Hz.
>  * Returns the signal in Volts after applying filter.
>  * 
>  * //y(n)=a*y(n-1)+(1-a)*x(n)
>  *
>  * 
>  *
>  * @param signalIn
>  * @return
>  */
> public float[] applyLmaxFilter(float[] signal) {
>
>     int n_samples = signal.length;
>
>     float[] x_signal = new float[n_samples];
>     float[] y_signal = new float[n_samples];
>     float[] ret_signal = new float[n_samples];
>
>
>     //Square the signal
>     for (int i_sample = 0; i_sample < n_samples; i_sample++) {
>         x_signal[i_sample] = signal[i_sample] * signal[i_sample];
>     }
>
>     //Exponential moving average parameters
>     float tau=0.125f;
>     float fs=44100f;
>     float alpha=tau/(1f/fs+tau);
>
>     //for the first sample 
>     y_signal[0] = initValue*alpha+(1-alpha)*x_signal[0];
>
>     //for the rest of the samples
>     for (int i_sample = 1; i_sample < n_samples; i_sample++) {
>         y_signal[i_sample] = y_signal[i_sample-1]*alpha+(1-alpha)*x_signal[i_sample];
>     }
>
>     //remember last sample for next time step;
>     initValue=y_signal[n_samples-1];
>
>     //Square root
>     for (int i_sample = 0; i_sample < n_samples; i_sample++) {
>         ret_signal[i_sample] = (float) Math.sqrt(y_signal[i_sample]);
>     } 
>
>     return ret_signal;
> }
> ```
>
> }